# PhpStorm WebStorm: change auto-import source resolution

Tags: import, module, phpstorm, webstorm

Here is my file structure

```
component.ts
/services
  first.service.ts
  second.service.ts
  index.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './first.service';
export * from './second.service';
```

From `component.ts`, I wish to use a service. This is how my IDE (PhpStorm/WebStorm) automatically generates the import code

```
import { FirstService } from './services/first.service'
```

Of course this works. But I would prefer:

```
import { FirstService } from './services/index'
```

Can this be tweaked through a setting?

#### Update

I've changed my mind about using barrel files all over my Angular project after reading [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301) about the subject. I would recommend reading it to anyone considering doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports`, enable **Use directory import (Node-style module resolution)** . When this checkbox is selected, import statements are generated in compliance with the Node.js [module resolution strategy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)